# Output feature class is arbitrarily split into sections by Arc GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, buffer

I’ve attached a picture illustrating my problem. In the picture areas 1, 2, 3 and 4 should all be joined as one polygon. Instead it looks like arc has split the polygon into four parts using a grid, see the lines.

My question is why has Arc GIS 10.3 (Advanced) done this? I know how I could fix this but I would like to prevent this from happening in the first place.

My starting data set was a shapefile containing points, I then ran a model which selected some of those points and buffered around them for 2 meters dissolving overlaps where they occur.

Model summary:

Iterate feature class = this imports my point feature class data

Make feature layer = converts a feature class to a layer

Select layer by attribute = selects all points with  “gridcode” > 0

Select layer by attribute = selects all points with  “p_value” < 0.05

Select layer by attribute = selects all points with  “value” > 1.96

Buffer = creates a 2m buffer around the selection and dissolves overlaps

END OF MODEL

[image: Picture]

Comment: I know that arc will automatically tile the input data to help with RAM usage while doing a buffer or dissolve.  However, it is supposed to put it back together in the end.  Someone else will probably know why this is happening.